# how to convert object that is convertible to double to a culture invariant string with one call in C#

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

ADO.NET DataRow object can have different type for a column depending on the RDBMS. E.g Oracle/SQLServer. However a real it's always possible to convert to double with

```
DataRow row = GetDataRow(id);
double x = Convert.ToDouble(row["X"]);
```

But do I really need to do following:

```
DataRow row = GetDataRow(id);
double x = Convert.ToDouble(row["X"]);
string  xStr = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or is there better way?

Comment: Does this work? I believe `InvariantCulture` is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: What is purpose of doing this? Why row["X"].ToString() is not an option?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Can't you read? Can I do it with one call directly as I ask in title.

Comment: @Reniuz: Because it can come out as 1,23 or 1.23 depending on current cultur

Comment: yes. force it to period, not comma.

Comment: @matti: if it's so important write an extension method `ToInvariantString`, then this works: `Convert.ToDouble(row["X"]).ToInvariantString()`. But is this an improvement? In my opinion not at all.

Comment: Ok mystery solved. Now what do you mean `in one call`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: no improvement. seems the answer is: no possible with 1 method call.

Comment: It depends what are you using. GetDataRow is that devexpress method?

Answer (score 0):

outside of creating an extension method, here's one line....   :)

```
string x = Convert.ToDouble(row["X"]).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Is this really worth an answer? If this _is_ the answer it was not a valid question.

Comment: No it isn't. It should be: `string x = Convert.ToDouble(GetDataRow(id)["X"]).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` then.

Comment: @TMcKeown: thanks for answer, but this is the same thing as I figured out in question. I'm interested in converting object to string with one call. Or mainly of the fact is it possible.

Comment: extension method is really the best option in my op... (like my answer indicates)  =)